# Mapkit and userTrackingMode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkusertrackingmode

I have a question about MapKit. I set the userTrackingMode property to move the map according to the user position update.

```
 [_mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

Is there a way to be alerted when you exit from this mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Apple Docs on [`MKMapViewDelegate Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3adidChangeUserTrackingMode%3aanimated%3a):

> **mapView:didChangeUserTrackingMode:animated:**
>   Tells the delegate that the user tracking mode changed.
>
> - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated